# How i can catch an exception raised inside an Exception block

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a .net console application, and i have the following code:-

```
try {
    SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
} catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e) {
    SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
} catch {}
```

now if an exception is raised inside the `try` block, the 2 other `catch` blocks will catch it, depending on the exception type!!. but if an exception is raised inside the `catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)` block then the console will end. now i thought if an exception is raised inside the `catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)` block, then the last `catch` block will be reached but seems this is not the case.. so can anyone advice how i can catch an exception raised inside an Exception block??

Comment: Use an inner `try/catch` block.

Comment: @Dai this is the only option ?

Comment: @bassfader now in my case it is not possible,, as i am adding files based on users actions... now if by chance the same file name exists, then i do not want to overwrite it ,, where the `Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false)` will raise an exception.. which is understandable/acceptable behavior  by me...

Comment: What does `Files.Add` do, exactly? What exceptions does it throw? If the `destUrl` doesn't exist and it throws then I guess it won't add anything to the collection (if it is a colleciton) so calling it again won't be any different.

Comment: @Dai the `destUrl` contains the folder name + the file name.. now if the file name already exists the `Files.Add` will raise an exception here is the method i am using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms428630.aspx

Comment: The idea behind catching an exception is that whatever you're doing in the catch block should be returning your application to a working state (whatever code follows should be able to assume the code in the try block was successful). What should your application do in the event that `projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(...)` throws another exception?

Comment: Wrap your calling code in a `try catch`

Comment: @Lee sorry i mistyped the code,, updated my code

Comment: Could you put `destUrl` and `destUrl2` in a list and iterate over it?

Comment: @TiesonT. to ignore the exception as in this case both files at `destUrl ` & `destUrl2 ` already exists and i do not want to override the files at both destinations

Comment: @Lee yes i think this will be possible,, but i am trying to avoid too much modification to my code

Comment: @Lee and you know iterating under a multi-users environment can leads to exception at certain situations... if the file was just added between iterations

Comment: Ok in that case I agree with the suggestions to add a nested `try/catch` in your outer `catch` block.

Comment: @Lee seems it is the only option.. thanks for ur valuable advice ..

Comment: Would it not make more sense to use a [File.Exists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) before trying to write the file, then? If you know that "file already exists" is a common state, it's not really an exception, and checking for the file should be part of the normal workflow.

Comment: @TiesonT. yes i never used `Files.Exists` but seems it is the right choice.. or as suggested by other users i can have an inner try/catch inside my current exception block

Answer (score 2):

To handle this, you have to write another `try .. catch` block inside the catch block that is handling `DirectoryNotFoundException`

Comment: so this is the only option to have an inner try catch ??

Comment: @johnG Yes, if you have to handle the exception here itself. BTW, you can also throw the exception and the calling method can handle it or you can just ignore it.

Comment: what do you mean by i can just ignore it

Comment: @johnG I mean, if Add method throws only unchecked exceptions and if you are sure that the exception will never be thrown in your use-case (and hence application wont terminate here) then you dont need to wrap it in a `try .. catch` block.
If my answer is helpful please accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You should notice that **try-catch should never be part of your code logic** which means you should never use try-catch to control your branch. This is the reason why you'll find it hard to let the exceptions flow through your each catch block.

If you'd like to catch the second block, you can write like this (but **not recommended**):

```
try
{
    SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
}
catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
{
    try
    {
        SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl2, fileBytes, false);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Do what you want to do.
    }
}
catch
{
}
```

You'd better not to write like this above. Instead, **it's recommended** to detect the folder exists ahead like this:

```
try
{
    YourMainMethod();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Handle common exceptions that you don't know when you write these codes.
}

void YourMainMethod()
{
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(destUrl);
    var directory2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(destUrl2);

    if (Directory.Exists(directory))
    {
        SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl, fileBytes, false);
    }
    else if (Directory.Exists(directory2))
    {
        SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destUrl2, fileBytes, false);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle the expected situations.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It might make more sense to use [File.Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) to see if the path already exists, and then attempt to write the file:

```cs
string path = null;

if(!File.Exists(destUrl))
{
    path = destUrl;
}
else
{
    if(!File.Exists(destUrl2))
    {
        path = destUrl2;
    }
}

if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
{
    try
    {
        SPFile destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(path, fileBytes, false);
    }
    catch
    {
        // Something prevented file from being written -> handle this as your workflow dictates
    }
}
```

Then, the only exception you would expect to happen is a failure to write the file, which you would need to handle as your application dictates (permission issues should be treated differently than invalid binary data, corrupted streams, etc.)

You might find this worth a read, if you haven't done so: [Best practices for exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you could be try-catching in huge nested statements.

If you have a list of destinations you want to try, then you could do something like this

```
var destinations = new List<string>() {dest1,dest2,dest3, ...};

SPFile destFile = null;

foreach(var destination in destinations)
{
    try
    {
        destFile = projectid.RootFolder.Files.Add(destination, fileBytes, false);
        // we are working
        Console.WriteLine($"Destination Success!!: {destination}");
        break;
    }
    catch(DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"Destination failed : {destination} - {ex.Message}");
    }
} 

if(destFile != null)
   // do something with your destFile 
else
   // oh noez!!!
```